# How to show/hide two views in one Marionette js region

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am having a `LayoutView` in which I am having **two regions** named **filter** region and **main** region (Content Region). Based on the selection over filter region, I need to show the view into the main region.

As of now, I have created one view to show into the main region i.e Current Year view, but I need inputs on how to create a view for the other Wireframe that I am attaching into my question panel now.

[image: CurrentYearView]

[image: PastYearView]

```js
// Application Bootstrap
var App = new Marionette.Application();

// Add a region
App.addRegions({
  main: "#app"
});

/*DATA*/
var data = {
  "accounts": [{
    "accountNumber": "AllAccounts",
    "assets": [{
        "assetName": "ASSET 1",
        "isin": "GB0008533564",
        "grossProfit": [{
          "assetCost": "500",
          "units": "10",
          "netGainLoss": "20"
        }]
      },
      {
        "assetName": "ASSET 2",
        "isin": "GB0008533565",
        "grossProfit": [{
          "assetCost": "500",
          "units": "10",
          "netGainLoss": "20"
        }]
      },
      {
        "assetName": "ASSET 3",
        "isin": "GB0008533566",
        "grossProfit": [{
          "assetCost": "500",
          "units": "10",
          "netGainLoss": "20"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

// AssetsModel
var AssetsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
//AssetsCollection - will contain the assets array
var AssetsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: AssetsModel,
  getAssetCost: function() {
    var assetCost = 0;
    this.each(function(model) {
      _(model.get('grossProfit')).each(function(gross) {
        assetCost += parseInt(gross.assetCost, 10);
      });
    });
    return assetCost;
  },
  getUnits: function() {
    var units = 0;
    this.each(function(model) {
      _(model.get('grossProfit')).each(function(gross) {
        units += parseInt(gross.units, 10);
      });
    });
    return units;
  },
  getNetGainLoss: function() {
    var netGainLoss = 0;
    this.each(function(model) {
      _(model.get('grossProfit')).each(function(gross) {
        netGainLoss += parseInt(gross.netGainLoss, 10);
      });
    });
    return netGainLoss;

  }
});

// AccountsModel - unique idAttribute will be accountNumber and setting the assets key of AccountsModel to AssetsCollection
var AccountsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "accountNumber",
  initialize: function(response) {
    this.set('assets', new AssetsCollection(response.assets));
  }
});

// AccountsCollection - will be containg the Acccounts Array
var AccountsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: AccountsModel
});

// Passing the data.accounts to accountsCollection instance
var accountsCollection = new AccountsCollection(data.accounts);

// AppLayoutView - mainlayoutview of the application 
var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile($("#layout-view-template").html()),
  regions: {
    filter: "#filterArea",
    main: "#contentArea" // mainContentArea regiobn- will be containing two type of views:
    // 1. High level view, with multiple assets as table row's and only one object inside grossProfit
    // 2. Deep level view, with multiple objects inside assets array as table and mutliple objects inside grossProfit array
    //   (second point, need to be discussed for which i am raising question)
  },
  onRender: function() {
    this.showChildView("filter", new FilterView());
    this.showChildView("main", new TableCompositeView({
      collection: accountsCollection.get('AllAccounts').get('assets')
    }));
  }
});

var FilterView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  id: "filter-view",
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#filter-view-template').html())
});

var RowView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#report-row-template').html())
});

var TableCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  id: "report-area-view",
  tagName: "section",
  template: Handlebars.compile($("#report-view-template").html()),
  childView: RowView,
  childViewContainer: "#childWrapper",
  templateHelpers: function() {
    var totalAssetCost = this.collection.getAssetCost();
    var totalUnits = this.collection.getUnits();
    var totalNetGainLoss = this.collection.getNetGainLoss();
    return {
      totalAssetCost: totalAssetCost,
      totalUnits: totalUnits,
      totalNetGainLoss: totalNetGainLoss
    }
  }
});



var layoutView = new AppLayoutView();

// Render the layoutView to the main Region
App.getRegion('main').show(layoutView);

App.start();
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="app"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--TEMPLATES -->
<script id="layout-view-template" type="text/handlebars-template">
  <section>
    <div id="filterArea"> </div>
    <div id="contentArea"> </div>
  </section>
</script>

<script id="filter-view-template" type="text/handlebars-template">
  <div class="well">
    <input type="radio" name="currentYear" value="currentYear" /> Current year <br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="twoYears" value="pastYears" /> Past 2 year
  </div>
</script>

<script id="report-view-template" type="text/handlebars-template">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Asset Name</th>
        <th>Asset Cost</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>NetGainLoss</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="childWrapper"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>&#8377; {{totalAssetCost}}</th>
        <th>&#8377; {{totalUnits}}</th>
        <th>&#8377; {{totalNetGainLoss}}</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</script>

<script id="report-row-template" type="text/handlebars-template">
  <td>{{assetName}}</td>
  {{#grossProfit}}
  <td>{{assetCost}}</td>
  <td>{{units}}</td>
  <td>{{netGainLoss}}</td>
  {{/grossProfit}}
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/2.4.2/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Please use the below data to show the Past 2 Years view, there is only minor changes i.e only the `grossProfit` array objects have been increased.

```
var data = {
  "accounts": [{
    "accountNumber": "AllAccounts",
    "assets": [{
        "assetName": "ASSET 1",
        "isin": "GB0008533564",
        "grossProfit": [{
            "assetCost": "500",
            "units": "10",
            "netGainLoss": "20"
          },
          {
            "assetCost": "500",
            "units": "10",
            "netGainLoss": "20"
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        "assetName": "ASSET 2",
        "isin": "GB0008533565",
        "grossProfit": [{
            "assetCost": "500",
            "units": "10",
            "netGainLoss": "20"
          },
          {
            "assetCost": "500",
            "units": "10",
            "netGainLoss": "20"
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        "assetName": "ASSET 3",
        "isin": "GB0008533566",
        "grossProfit": [{
            "assetCost": "500",
            "units": "10",
            "netGainLoss": "20"
          },
          {
            "assetCost": "1000",
            "units": "10",
            "netGainLoss": "20"
          }

        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
};
```

Comment: Validations on the site is for improving questions. -1 for bypassing validations and not posting code sample in question. I'm voting to close this question since it doesn't contain any code related to what you're describing (External links don't count because they can go down and question becomes obsolete). Please follow the site rules

Comment: I have checked in to the code recently and was not aware of the query that you are annotating , so will be great if anyone can help me with the issue instead of putting negative ticks . Thanks

Comment: You need to follow the site rules and post proper questions if you want to receive better answers.

Comment: What modification should I do right now in order to meet the requirements of the site . Please share your comments I will do that to

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:If you have to show completely different composite view within the main region,you have to create a separate layout 'ResultLayout' which should be rendered in Main Region.You can intialized both the compositeview's in ResultLayout and render the desired compositeview when the filter is changed.(This is the case when your data is static for different filters)

In case of dynamic data
Case 2: If you have to show completely different composite view within the main region, you have to create a separate layout 'ResultLayout' which should be rendered in Main Region.You can render the desired compositeview when the filter is changed.
For first time you can show default filter selected and corresponding compositeview is render within the layout(ResultLayout) of main region.

On filter change you can trigger event from FilterView which will be listened in ResultLayout (with filter params), fetch the collection according to the filters and then you can render the corresponding compositeview in the region of 'ResultLayout' 
The hierarchy will be as below:

LayoutView -> Filter Region and Main Region

Main Region -> ResultLayout

ResultLayout -> CompositeView1 or CompositeView2 (Depending upon the filters.)

Case 3: If you have to keep compositeview same then you just need to update the collection and render the view.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I am new to marionette and backbone , will be great if you can update the codepen for me according to the wireframe that I have attached.

Comment: Will be a great help , bcoz I have tried on my own but stuck like how to show / hide the things . Coz if you will see the data is different on both the cases and the HTML structure is also different that's why I am stuck

Comment: Will you tell me the case which you are expecting from the cases I have mentioned above

Comment: Case 2 will be good I suppose , coz the data will be dynamic. If you will see the wireframe s will be great and the codepen example that I have created . I guess case 2 will be good but somehow if there is any way by which if we can club them both that will be great . Thanks